# How to open new tab, not new window in chrome using JS?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs, window

I have mined deep in the web, but still I cannot find a solution for this problem, i.e., when you manually click a link in the webpage, it will open a new tab in Chrome, but when you click it by invoking *link.click()* in JS, it will open a new window.
Is it possible to find a way for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get this behavior programmatically, this behavior set by user inside browser configuration :(